# PowerShell: Duplicated Files, exclude Folder, and delete if same name/size

Tags: powershell, recursion, path, duplicates

I am really new into powershell, I googled alot and merged my results into this, but to begin with, my folder structure is like this:

- **test-neu**

  - _bewertet

    - *1.txt*
    - *2.txt*
  - 1

    - *1.txt*
    - *2.txt*
  - 2

    - *1.txt*
    - *3.txt*
    - *4.txt*
  - ...

My goal is to look for all the files stored in **_bewertet** and if these files also exist in any other subfolder than itself (regarding, filename and size), it should be deleted in there. So to be clear, the files should stay in **_bewertet** but nowhere else.

```
$ignore = @("*_bewertet*");
$one = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\Users\name\Desktop\test-neu\_bewertet
$two = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\Users\name\Desktop\test-neu -Exclude $ignore | ? { $_.PSIsContainer }

$matches = (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $one -DifferenceObject $two -Property Name,Length -ExcludeDifferent -IncludeEqual)

foreach ($file in $matches)
{
    Remove-Item C:\Users\name\Desktop\test-neu\$($file.Name)
}
```

So far, it really does nothing if I run my script..., my guess is, the Remove-Item part needs to be adjusted. The path just goes to **C:\Users\name\Desktop\test-neu\1.txt** for example and so the appropriate subfolder is missing.

If you guys could help me out there, that would mean alot to me. Any suggestions are welcome. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: You should look at the results of `Compare-Object` first. If it is empty then the loop would not happen. If there are results you should retrieve the file objects again by use `Select -Expand InputObject` after the compare object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest logic I could come up with, to achieve this goal

```
$keep = Dir -Path t:\bewertet -Recurse
$allFiles = Dir -Path t:\ -Recurse -Include *.txt | Where Directory -NotLike "t:\bewertet*"
$allFiles | Where Name -in $keep.Name | Remove-Item
```

`$Keep` defines the list of files in the bewertet folder.
`$allFiles` defines a list of all files recursively, specifying only .txt files, and where the directory is not t:\bewertet.

Finally, we filter through `$allFiles`, finding files with matching name to the files in `$keep` and then remove each of those.

## Even more better

OP came back and said `We forgot to check if it's the same size!`, so being that I'm in the Christmas Spirit, I wrote this lazy comparison.

```
$keep = gci t:\bewertet -Recurse

$allFiles = dir -Path t:\ -Recurse -Include *.txt | Where Directory -NotLike "t:\bewertet*"

$matches = $allFiles | ? Name -in $keep.Name 

ForEach ($match in $matches){
    $source = $keep | ? Name -eq $match.Name
    $Samefile = ($source.Length -eq $match.length)
    "Does file size match? [$Samefile]"

        if ($Samefile){
            "deleting..."
            Remove-item $match
            }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this works like a charm. I knew there might be a short solution. I just tested it in my setup, now I will take a bit more time to understand it completely. Thank you Sir :)

Comment: Happy to help.  Mine just looks a bit more complex because I'm specifying all of the parameter names for `Dir`, instead of using positional parameters, etc.

Comment: Not taking file size into account though

Comment: Damn, yeah I just realized the missing file size argument...how to take this into account?

Comment: Thank you very much, i appreciate your christmas spirit ;)